# Dynamic editable table with formArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'mk trying to make a dynamic editable table like this with a formArray. The years vary, so I need it to be dynamic.

[image]

but i don't get to show the inputs, only the header titles. I'm trying to set the formControlNames using the column. name set. Any help would be great. I don't get any errors in console

I have made a stackblitz--> [stackblitz Angular 13](https://simple-angular-mat-table-example-zrfynb.stackblitz.io)

Thanks a lot in advance